# How to retrieve json object in ajax onreadystatechange function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I have servlet calling in ajax call. It send `json` object in response. Now I have receive this json in `jsp` and place data in table format. Can someone help me in this. Here is my code,

I am calling servlet as,

`xmlHttpReqRM.open('POST', "RTMobitor?rtype=rmonitor", true);`

my servlet, Here `vehicleList` is a `list` object

```
latlng.setLng(resultSet.getString("lng"));
latlng.setStatus(resultSet.getString("status"));
latlng.setRdate(resultSet.getString("rdate"));
latlng.setRtime(resultSet.getString("rtime"));
vehicleList.add(latlng);
System.out.println(vehicleList);
String json = new Gson().toJson(vehicleList);
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Previously I was sending response as a text, it was easy but now I changed to `json`. I am not getting how to receive,

```
xmlHttpReqRM.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (xmlHttpReqRM.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlHttpReqRM.status == 200) {
        var responceeString = xmlHttpReqRM.responseText; // How to replace this ajax code for json
        document.getElementById("flexme1").innerHTML = (responceeString);
    } else {
        alert('ERR OR: AJAX request status = ' + xmlHttpReqRM.status);
    }
```

How can I replace this `ajax` code for json. Can anyone help me in this please.

Comment: What are you really asking here, you're using jQuery, yet you're not really using it and making stuff really complicated for yourself ?

Comment: I have table, now my ajax code receives responseText but I have to get Json and place json data to table.

Comment: You're not getting it, if you're using jQuery just delete all that crap and to this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/gagygtor/**

Comment: yes that JQuery, I m not using

Comment: yes just for testing i put that , my actual code is this updates one.

Answer (score 0):

> var jsonObject = JSON.parse(responceeString);

Comment: what is there in `responceeString`

Comment: yes it worked . . how can I display it to table, when I check with `alert(jsonObject)` it shows `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`